# Which is the header file of CUDA Math Library?

Tags: api, math, cuda

I tried to use cuda math api such as sqrtf(), __fdividef() and got errors like the following:

```
error C3861: '__fdividef':Identifier not found
error C3861: 'rsqrtf':Identifier not found
```

It seems "NVIDIA CUDA Math API" didn't specify which header we're supposed to include when we want to use these apis. In helper_math.h, it looks like the function e.g.

```
inline __host__ __device__ float length(float4 v)
{
    return sqrtf(dot(v, v));
}
```

use the implementation of sqrtf from c library math.h, isn't it a host function without a **device** identifier? Can we use it directly in our **device** function?

Please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you really need CUDA math header files to compile the above function?

Comment: @JackOLantern Of course, I'm not sure, and that's why I posted it here. I was wondering the length(float4 v) function call the sqrtf() function, and the latter one should also be device function, right? Otherwise, we will be calling host function from device function, which is not possible in cuda programming model, if I remember correctly. I guess there is a function with the following style : inline __host__ __device float sqrtf(float v). Right?

Comment: @JackOLantern Well, after a code refactoring, I fixed the error. And yes, you're right, we don't need to include cuda math headers explictly. BTW, the math api functions are located in device_functinons.h and they're not supposed not be included in user's code. But it's good to know which fundamental api they actually use to implement these math apis.

Comment: can someone please answer the question?  G_fans you can answer your own question to explain what you did to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Previously, I implemented the code like this:

```
// This implementation follows the code from
// https://github.com/erwincoumans/experiments/blob/master/opencl/primitives/AdlPrimitives/Math/MathCL.h

#ifndef UNIFIED_MATH_CUDA_H
#define UNIFIED_MATH_CUDA_H

#include "vector_functions.h"

/*****************************************
Vector
/*****************************************/

__device__
    float fastDiv(float numerator, float denominator)
{
    return __fdividef(numerator, denominator);        
    //return numerator/denominator;        
}

__device__
    float getSqrtf(float f2)
{
    return sqrtf(f2);
}

__device__
    float getReverseSqrt(float f2)
{
    return rsqrtf(f2);
}

__device__
    float3 getCrossProduct(float3 a, float3 b)
{
    return make_float3(a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x); 
}

__device__
    float4 getCrossProduct(float4 a, float4 b)
{
    float3 v1 = make_float3(a.x, a.y, a.z);
    float3 v2 = make_float3(b.x, b.y, b.z);
    float3 v3 = make_float3(a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x); 

    return make_float4(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, 0.0f);
}

__device__
    float getDotProduct(float3 a, float3 b)
{
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}

__device__
    float getDotProduct(float4 a, float4 b)
{
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z + a.w * b.w;
}

__device__ float3 getNormalizedVec(const float3 v)
{
    float invLen = 1.0f / sqrtf(getDotProduct(v, v));
    return make_float3(v.x * invLen, v.y * invLen, v.z * invLen);
}

__device__ float4 getNormalizedVec(const float4 v)
{
    float invLen = 1.0f / sqrtf(getDotProduct(v, v));
    return make_float4(v.x * invLen, v.y * invLen, v.z * invLen, v.w * invLen);
}

__device__
    float dot3F4(float4 a, float4 b)
{
    float4 a1 = make_float4(a.x, a.y, a.z,0.f);
    float4 b1 = make_float4(b.x, b.y, b.z,0.f);
    return getDotProduct(a1, b1);
}

__device__
    float getLength(float3 a)
{
    return sqrtf(getDotProduct(a, a));
}

__device__
    float getLength(float4 a)
{
    return sqrtf(getDotProduct(a, a));
}

/*****************************************
Matrix3x3
/*****************************************/

typedef struct
{
    float4 m_row[3];
}Matrix3x3_d;

__device__
    void setZero(Matrix3x3_d& m)
{
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getZeroMatrix3x3()
{
    Matrix3x3_d m;
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    return m;
}

__device__ 
    void setIdentity(Matrix3x3_d& m)
{
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(1,0,0,0);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0,1,0,0);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0,0,1,0);
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getIdentityMatrix3x3()
{
    Matrix3x3_d m;
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(1,0,0,0);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0,1,0,0);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0,0,1,0);
    return m;
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getTranspose(const Matrix3x3_d m)
{
    Matrix3x3_d out;
    out.m_row[0] = make_float4(m.m_row[0].x, m.m_row[1].x, m.m_row[2].x, 0.f);
    out.m_row[1] = make_float4(m.m_row[0].y, m.m_row[1].y, m.m_row[2].y, 0.f);
    out.m_row[2] = make_float4(m.m_row[0].z, m.m_row[1].z, m.m_row[2].z, 0.f);
    return out;
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d MatrixMul(Matrix3x3_d& a, Matrix3x3_d& b)
{
    Matrix3x3_d transB = getTranspose( b );
    Matrix3x3_d ans;
    //        why this doesn't run when 0ing in the for{}
    a.m_row[0].w = 0.f;
    a.m_row[1].w = 0.f;
    a.m_row[2].w = 0.f;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        //        a.m_row[i].w = 0.f;
        ans.m_row[i].x = dot3F4(a.m_row[i],transB.m_row[0]);
        ans.m_row[i].y = dot3F4(a.m_row[i],transB.m_row[1]);
        ans.m_row[i].z = dot3F4(a.m_row[i],transB.m_row[2]);
        ans.m_row[i].w = 0.f;
    }
    return ans;
}

__device__
    float4 MatrixVectorMul(Matrix3x3_d a, float4 b)
{
    float4 ans;
    ans.x = dot3F4( a.m_row[0], b );
    ans.y = dot3F4( a.m_row[1], b );
    ans.z = dot3F4( a.m_row[2], b );
    ans.w = 0.f;
    return ans;
}


#endif  // UNIFIED_MATH_CUDA_H
```

Since cuda will automatically inline all the device code, I ignored the inline identifier. But It came with the error as I stated in the question:

```
error C3861: '__fdividef':Identifier not found
error C3861: 'rsqrtf':Identifier not found
```

Then I reimplemented following the tradional c/c++ style as following.

UnifiedMathCUDA.cuh:

```
// This implementation follows the code from
// https://github.com/erwincoumans/experiments/blob/master/opencl/primitives/AdlPrimitives/Math/MathCL.h

#ifndef UNIFIED_MATH_CUDA_H
#define UNIFIED_MATH_CUDA_H

#include "vector_functions.h"

/*****************************************
                Vector
/*****************************************/

__device__
    float fastDiv(float numerator, float denominator);

__device__
    float getSqrtf(float f2);

__device__
    float getReverseSqrt(float f2);

__device__
    float3 getCrossProduct(float3 a, float3 b);

__device__
    float4 getCrossProduct(float4 a, float4 b);

__device__
    float getDotProduct(float3 a, float3 b);

__device__
    float getDotProduct(float4 a, float4 b);

__device__ float3 getNormalizedVec(const float3 v);

__device__ float4 getNormalizedVec(const float4 v);

__device__
    float dot3F4(float4 a, float4 b);

__device__
    float getLength(float3 a);

__device__
    float getLength(float4 a);

/*****************************************
                Matrix3x3
/*****************************************/
typedef struct
{
    float4 m_row[3];
}Matrix3x3_d;

__device__
    void setZero(Matrix3x3_d& m);

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getZeroMatrix3x3();

__device__ 
    void setIdentity(Matrix3x3_d& m);

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getIdentityMatrix3x3();

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getTranspose(const Matrix3x3_d m);

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d MatrixMul(Matrix3x3_d& a, Matrix3x3_d& b);

__device__
    float4 MatrixVectorMul(Matrix3x3_d a, float4 b);


#endif  // UNIFIED_MATH_CUDA_H
```

and the correspoding implementaion file is like this:

```
#include "UnifiedMathCUDA.cuh"

/*****************************************
                Vector
/*****************************************/

__device__
    float fastDiv(float numerator, float denominator)
{
    return __fdividef(numerator, denominator);        
    //return numerator/denominator;        
}

__device__
    float getSqrtf(float f2)
{
    return sqrtf(f2);
}

__device__
    float getReverseSqrt(float f2)
{
    return rsqrtf(f2);
}

__device__
    float3 getCrossProduct(float3 a, float3 b)
{
    return make_float3(a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x); 
}

__device__
    float4 getCrossProduct(float4 a, float4 b)
{
    float3 v1 = make_float3(a.x, a.y, a.z);
    float3 v2 = make_float3(b.x, b.y, b.z);
    float3 v3 = make_float3(a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x); 

    return make_float4(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, 0.0f);
}

__device__
    float getDotProduct(float3 a, float3 b)
{
     return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}

__device__
    float getDotProduct(float4 a, float4 b)
{
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z + a.w * b.w;
}

__device__ float3 getNormalizedVec(const float3 v)
{
    float invLen = 1.0f / sqrtf(getDotProduct(v, v));
    return make_float3(v.x * invLen, v.y * invLen, v.z * invLen);
}

__device__ float4 getNormalizedVec(const float4 v)
{
    float invLen = 1.0f / sqrtf(getDotProduct(v, v));
    return make_float4(v.x * invLen, v.y * invLen, v.z * invLen, v.w * invLen);
}

__device__
    float dot3F4(float4 a, float4 b)
{
    float4 a1 = make_float4(a.x, a.y, a.z,0.f);
    float4 b1 = make_float4(b.x, b.y, b.z,0.f);
    return getDotProduct(a1, b1);
}

__device__
    float getLength(float3 a)
{
    return sqrtf(getDotProduct(a, a));
}

__device__
    float getLength(float4 a)
{
    return sqrtf(getDotProduct(a, a));
}

/*****************************************
                Matrix3x3
/*****************************************/

__device__
    void setZero(Matrix3x3_d& m)
{
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getZeroMatrix3x3()
{
    Matrix3x3_d m;
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    return m;
}

__device__ 
    void setIdentity(Matrix3x3_d& m)
{
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(1,0,0,0);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0,1,0,0);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0,0,1,0);
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getIdentityMatrix3x3()
{
    Matrix3x3_d m;
    m.m_row[0] = make_float4(1,0,0,0);
    m.m_row[1] = make_float4(0,1,0,0);
    m.m_row[2] = make_float4(0,0,1,0);
    return m;
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d getTranspose(const Matrix3x3_d m)
{
    Matrix3x3_d out;
    out.m_row[0] = make_float4(m.m_row[0].x, m.m_row[1].x, m.m_row[2].x, 0.f);
    out.m_row[1] = make_float4(m.m_row[0].y, m.m_row[1].y, m.m_row[2].y, 0.f);
    out.m_row[2] = make_float4(m.m_row[0].z, m.m_row[1].z, m.m_row[2].z, 0.f);
    return out;
}

__device__
    Matrix3x3_d MatrixMul(Matrix3x3_d& a, Matrix3x3_d& b)
{
    Matrix3x3_d transB = getTranspose( b );
    Matrix3x3_d ans;
    //        why this doesn't run when 0ing in the for{}
    a.m_row[0].w = 0.f;
    a.m_row[1].w = 0.f;
    a.m_row[2].w = 0.f;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        //        a.m_row[i].w = 0.f;
        ans.m_row[i].x = dot3F4(a.m_row[i],transB.m_row[0]);
        ans.m_row[i].y = dot3F4(a.m_row[i],transB.m_row[1]);
        ans.m_row[i].z = dot3F4(a.m_row[i],transB.m_row[2]);
        ans.m_row[i].w = 0.f;
    }
    return ans;
}

__device__
    float4 MatrixVectorMul(Matrix3x3_d a, float4 b)
{
    float4 ans;
    ans.x = dot3F4( a.m_row[0], b );
    ans.y = dot3F4( a.m_row[1], b );
    ans.z = dot3F4( a.m_row[2], b );
    ans.w = 0.f;
    return ans;
}
```

Now, Problem solved!